# sum of max flow in residual graph and value of flow

Tags: network-flow

My teacher today explained us this . Consider a network and suppose that at any stage during the application of the Edmonds Karp algorithm to find the max flow, let

```
f = value of flow in the network at this stage 
t = value of the max flow in the residual graph of this flow 
F* = max possible value of flow in the original graph [which will be finally outputted by the whole algorithm]
```

He claimed that

```
f+t = F*.
```

I am not able to prove this. Can someone please help?

EDIT : I am certain that if we prove that each time we augment the flow , the value of the max flow in residual graph decreases by the amount by which we augment the original flow , then we would be done , since in the beginning

```
f = 0
t = F*
```

Comment: Can you show $F^* \geq f+t$? How about the opposite direction? Which one are you stuck at?

Comment: I am not able to get either . Can you please explain.

Comment: Well, I suggest you give it a try and prove at least one of the directions.

Comment: I donot understand "max flow in residual graph" completely .. i guess this means that considering the residual graph as another network with capacities as the current weights , the max flow in this network is t .. correct me if i am wrong .. moreover i am not able to relate this max flow in residual graph with value of flow in original graph ..

Comment: Your understand is correct, but I'm afraid you'll have to make more effort working on the question yourself. Try to combine the flow $f$ and a flow in the residual graph to a better flow on the original graph.

Comment: Well, i got it .. first i produced a flow in the original graph of value f+t. This proved that f+t<= F. Then i showed that there exists a cut in the graph for this flow s.t. capacity of the cut = value of flow = f+t .. This showed that f+t flow is actually the max flow and so f+t=F*

Comment: Now it remains for you to answer your own question with this explanation.